# css for a comples header with 3 background colors

Tags: html, css, background, header

This is a header design for a html i am doing. Ignore the cyan lines. They are photoshop guides

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gfym6.png

Now as you can see my container is 1230px.
the left side extends white background infinitely.
and the right side extends the combination of blue and grey in background infinitely (60px and 40px).

I cannot put widths in %age. I need them constant. How do i achieve this using css without using background images.

EDITED:
This is what im working around with: (please put http. i was unable to place this link. someone help how to accopmay this by "code" as well)
    jsfiddle.net/ue9QN/1/

I am fine with html css mainly. All i need to achieve is the 3 colors part. And at the same time I need them liquid.

So as in the jfiddle.
    black : background body
lightblue : container (i need this fixed pixel and centered in body)
light orange : logo area (i need this fixed pixel)
blue and green : they must extend infinitely towawds right. 
although my content in blue part will ofcourse lie within the 960px zone.
Please Help me achieve this. rest i can handle.

Regards,

Answer (score 2):

This can be easily achieved in a relatively cross-browser manner through floats.

The way I did it was:

- I floated your "logo" pane to the left and put a fixed size div in there to simulate your image.
- The `image + Hello! + cog` thing I floated to the right with no specific width. I did put 1em of padding on it.
- The menu is just a slightly styled `ul li` with 1em of padding. I tried to make it look simliar to your image, but I didn't put a lot of time beyond some `box-shadow`s and `text-shadow`s, but I think you should be able to take it from there. I am no artist.
- As for your white bar, this is where some creative sizing comes in. The `header` which contains the whole thing has `overflow: hidden;` set. This is a mild hack which causes it to be sure to contain all the elements inside, including floats. Clearfix can be used as well, but I've found `overflow: hidden` to handle nesting better. I made the bar have an exact height of `70px` and each `li` in the main menu have an height of exactly `30px`. The logo image also plays a part. That div is exactly `120px` tall so that the white from your logo box ends at the same time as the grey from the crossbar.
- The order of the elements is important. By putting the two floated elements first, I made sure that the following non-floated block elements would take up as much space as possible, but leave space for the float elements that were already there. This makes the grey bar and the menu take up as much horizontal space as they can until they bump into the logo box or the login hello thing in the right corner.

You can change up the sizes so it matches your thing...I was just throwing this together and that's what I came up with.

Here is the source: http://8155ce4e9bc7ef06828a-bcafea3713132d2e5fc10e6f32dd6212.r86.cf1.rackcdn.com/randomheader.html

I used [bootstrap css](http://getbootstrap.com) just for the icons and container class, but it should be simple enough to modify it to work without it. Bootstrap did the following which you can replicate without it (although, bootstrap is an excellent way to make a page look pretty with minimal effort):

- `box-sizing: border-box` is set on just about everything. This causes the padding and border to be included in the width. Without this, the width sets the width of the inside of the element, before the padding and border are applied. Its a real pain to calculate that stuff, especially in `em`s, so this really helps.
- The `container` div is a responsive mostly fixed width container. Bootstrap fixes it up so that it changes its fixed width based on the overall width of the page (read: screen size). You can just replace it with a simple `.container { width: 1230px; }` if you want. However, not everyone has a monitor that wide and the most up-to-date websites can handle differently sized monitors, so you may want to go with something a little more responsive than just a fixed hard `1230px`.

**Note about stack overflow questions:** It is expected that you have tried something and can show your effort. For next time, try something first and be sure to post it.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply. Although i am sorry i wsa not able to understand much. First of all. Let me show you what im playing around with. 
http://jsfiddle.net/ue9QN/1/

I am fine with html css mainly. All i need to achieve is the 3 colors part. And at the same time I need them liquid.

So as in the jfiddle.
black = background
lightblue = container (i need this fixed pixel and centered in body)
light orange = logo area (i need this fixed pixel)
blue and green = they must extend infinitely towawds right. 
although my content in blue part will ofcourse lie within the 960px zone.

Comment: I have modified your jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/gcJ52/1/. I did something a little different since you were just using divs. I did what is called the "holy grail" 3-column layout without the right column: https://www.google.com/search?q=holy+grail+of+css. This works by having your logo (`#a`) float left with a fixed width and your two content bars (`#b`, `#c`) not floating and having enough margin to make room for the floated div's width.

Comment: Also, to get a background to extend the full length of the page, apply the style to the `body` element. Additionally, using `width:100%` on divs can have unexpected effects since rather than telling it to take up as much space as possible, it is telling it to take up the same width as its parent. With padding and borders, this can get weird. Divs already try to take up as much space as possible (`display: block` does this).

Comment: Also, updated jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/gcJ52/2/ since there were a few height issues.